# get text from element using css selector excluding text inside nested element

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I need to get the text from the span using css selector, but excluding the text inside sup:

```
<span>(6-4, 7-6<sup>4</sup>)</span>
```

I tried this css selector but didn't worked:

```
span :not(sup)
# soup.select_one('span :not(sup)').text
```

The result I need is like this:
"(6-4, 7-6)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the text of only the parent element and exclude the text of all child elements.

```
span_element = soup.find('span')
span_text = span_element.find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

OUTPUT:
`6-4, 7-6`

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup, you can use the [`find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method:

```
print(soup.select_one('span').find_next(text=True))
```